# PHP Parse error in my WP plugin - works on one machine but not the other

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom WordPress plugin that works fine on my local dev machine, but triggers an error on the production server.

**The function:**

```
function _iniloader_get_dirs($dir) {
        $dirs = array_filter(scandir($dir), function ($item) use ($dir) {
            return (is_dir($dir.'/'.$item) && $item != "." && $item != "..");
        });
        // Use array_values to reset the array keys:
        return array_values($dirs);
}
```

**The error:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in (in plugin) on
>   line 30

Line 30 is the second line of the function.

My local MAMP server = PHP Version 5.3.6
Linux production server = PHP Version 5.3.5

Does anyone have an idea what the issue could be, and why it would show up in one environment but not the other?

---

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed that, if I put this function in a regular PHP file on the production box, it executes fine- so it's only triggering the error when it's part of the WordPress plugin, which makes even less sense to me...

Comment: You are probably mistaken about the production server. Use `print PHP_VERSION;` in the invocation script to find out the version.

Comment: It may also be useful if you could provide us with the difference between the phpinfo() function output on the two machines.

Comment: I could imagine wordpress is foreced to an older php version via htaccess or something. Please post the ouptput of `phpversion()` called from inside the Wordpress plugin.

Comment: Took Mario's advice and sure enough, `print PHP_VERSION` within WordPress shows 5.2.11 (phpinfo() on the server showed 5.3, didn't realize WP would be running on something else...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely it's your usage of [Closures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

These became available in PHP > 5.3. Your Production server is either not running 5.3 or a minor version that might be buggy.

Refactor the `use` clause and I imagine it will run on both environments.

Comment: Looks like you're right. Can you provide guidance on how to convert this to <5.3? How exactly would you refactor the `use` clause without rewriting the whole function?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You will have to use a [traditional callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) which will require you to *rewrite the whole function*.